# How do I install NPM packages while ignoring semvar?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm having a problem where some recent update (in the last week) to a dependency of a dependency is causing a breaking error in Safari. I have all of my versions set to exact in `package.json` but their dependencies are obviously going to pull using semvar version ranges. My old `package-lock.json` has invalid checksums now so that isn't working.

How do I rebuild my `node_modules` using the lowest specified versions of dependencies (ignoring semvar/version ranges)? I want to get the exact specified packages for all dependencies without automatically pulling a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example: `foo" = "~1.0.1,`

Comment: This only sets the version range to be minor versions. I can't do this on dependency package.json files either.

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan - You should go in to detail and explain why this is the correct answer.

Comment: i had same problem, and my solution was: set lowest version for package